# How to keep track of selections from UIPickerView in UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitextview, uipickerview

I have this project with a UITextView that is to show my selections from a UIPickerView. I already can show the selection, but when I pick another selection it overwrites the previous one and I need to keep track of all selections I make.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Você comprou %@ %@ e pagará R$ %.2f.",
                 [quantidade objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]],
                 [produtos objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]], total];


texto.text = msg;
```

Anyone could help???  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to create a instance variable in your view controller, a NSMutableString. Then, each time, you choose a new value from your picker view, just append new selection in your string, like :

In .h

```
NSMutableString *mutableStr;
```

In .m

```
// In your init
mutableStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];

// When a selection is made
[mutableStr appendFormat:@"Você comprou %@ %@ e pagará R$ %.2f.",
                 [quantidade objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]],
                 [produtos objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]], total];
```